# why "ordering": false not working in another table

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have 3 data tables. I'd like to remove the order and show the data table style. I'm currently using `"ordering": "false"` this worked for 2 of the data tables, but one is still ordered.

Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable( {
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "ordering": "false"
            });
            $('#example1').DataTable( {
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "ordering": "false"

            });
            $('#example2').DataTable( {
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "ordering": "false"

            });
```

Comment: "false" as a string is not the same as false as a boolean.

Comment: I cant see any python in this code. It looks like jquery to me. You might need to change "false" to false. No quotes.

Comment: @MEdwin already edited with no python hehe. i already tried just false, but style of datatable is gone

Comment: @TryaSoviKartikasari it should be false. If something is thrown off by that then tyou have other issues.

Comment: thankyou very much! @basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be **boolean** value in ordering.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "ordering": false // boolean type value
});
```

for more visit [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering).

Comment: thankyou, it worked, here is the code
$('#example').DataTable( {
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "ordering": false
            });